# Clear text box after choose certain option on select box

Tags: html, forms

I have a select box and text box like this :

```
<?php
    $receipt="12345";
?>

<form>
    <select name="sent" id="sent">            
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select> 

    <input type="text" name="receipt" value="<?=$receipt?>">
</form>
```

how can I clear the textbox after I choose option **No** ?

Comment: In JavaScript, or in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with [jQuery change method](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

create variable `receipt`

```
var receipt = "12345"; //replace 12345 with <?php echo $receipt;?>
```

bind select element with jQuery change method`$("#sent").change(function ()`

check select element value against `var receipt` and if true, clear the input.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var receipt = "123456";
 $("#sent").change(function () {
  var sel = $(this).val();
  if (sel == 0) {
   $("input[name=receipt]").val("");
  } else {
   $("input[name=receipt]").val(receipt);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select name="sent" id="sent">
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="receipt" value="123456">
</form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkjp7ydg/)

Answer (score 0):

try this one
its work
i have try it

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function Clear()
{
    var sent = document.getElementById('sent').value;
    if(sent==0){
        document.getElementById("receipt").value="";
    }


}
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $receipt="12345";
?>

<form>
    <select name="sent" id="sent" onchange="Clear()">            
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select> 

    <input type="text" id="receipt" name="receipt" value="<?=$receipt?>">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $receipt="12345";
?>

<script>
function SetField(val)
{
    if(val==0)
        document.getElementById('input-field').value='';
    else
        document.getElementById('input-field').value='<?php echo $receipt;?>';
}
</script>
<form>
    <select name="sent" id="sent" onchange="SetField(this.value);">            
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select> 

    <input type="text" id="input-field" name="receipt" value="<?=$receipt?>">
</form>
```

Much compact